# SPFx package doesn't show up in Apps

Tags: spfx

I created an SPFx package to deploy on SharePoint on prem 2019. I add the package to App Catalog it deployed Successfully, but then it doesn't show up in Apps on my site. Has anybody had the same problems?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happend to me multiple times, Now i need you to check in the App Catalog that the following field is presented there or not :

- Language Resources

You can refer to [William's blog](https://wiliammbr.com/spfx-solutions-not-showing-apps-sharepoint/)

Please notice in his blog he was talking about installing Feature Pack 2 for SP2016, you need to fetch the same Pack with the required features for SP2019.

Answer (score 0):

Some time this issue may arise due to feature is not deployed or installed properly.

Please follow the below steps to resolve this issue.

1. UnInstall the app and Remove it from the site.
2. Remove the app from app package from app catalog.
3. Increment the version of SPFx package.
4. Redeploy the package and install it.

Please mark as answer if it resolve the issue.

Thanks